# C# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Error 500 loading glyphicon and jquery ui style

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently coding a scheduler in C# ASP NET MVC 5.

Yesterday I deploy my application on a local IIS Server and I've noticed that my glyphicons and my jquery ui's styles don't work anymore 
[(error 500 in my web tools)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7C3Q.png).

I've tried many solutions of stackoverflow already, like many topic on an e

The error bring me to 
[my jquery bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1CVU.png)

The problem is that even localy, the glyphicons doen't work as well.

This is the differents solution i've already test:

- Loading my bundle with differents names to avoid name folder's conflicts
- Create a bundle with a CssRewriteUrlTransform
- Download fonts from bootstrap's website and insert them manually
- Configure IIS Mime Type to load correctly .ttf, .woff, .woff2

I will carry on with my reasearch and any help is welcome

Have good day guys,

D. =)

[Edit] I add the _Layout.cshtml as you ask ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Planning</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") 
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/cssjqryUi")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/fullcalendarcss")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap-theme")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/awesome")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
   @Html.Action("_Menu", "Layout")

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Si2A Planning</p>
    </footer>
</div>



@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap") 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcalendarjs")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/planifier")
```

[Edit] Web.Config file, only the part who was incorrect. It was an Appsetting missing.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://xxxxxxx"/>
    <add name="PlanningEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PlanningBDD.csdl|res://*/Models.PlanningBDD.ssdl|res://*/Models.PlanningBDD.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=xxxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

Comment: can you add your _layout.cshtml code here.

Comment: I add it as you ask. But the problem was in the web.config. I have probably add a line or change a line I shouldn't have.

Comment: Thanks ! Kindly add the web.config too if it's fine with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

)

Alright, so i've fix it.

My web.config was "corrupt". There is a line (still looking for it) with an error.

For now, if you met this error, Create a new ASP MVC App -> and copy section by section the "fresh" web.config into your old one.

This will fix this error of compilation.

I will update this answer to keep an history on this error and when i will find the real source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and managed to fix it by putting an entry in the web.config for the MIME types.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I've already tried this and nothing change. (local and IIS)